# How to save in photoshop image with layer style?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, information-graphics, layer-style

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hello everyone, I have an issue I can solve and I tried many thing but never succeeded,
so, in the first picture I have a smart object (based on vector file) when I copy it to photoshop it comes with black circles, I put the image on ***screen*** to avoid the black circles
But, when I save the image the png image still have the ***black circles***.
I will appreciate any help, I hope any of you guys can help me solve this.

Thank you everyone, And have a great day.

Comment: Have you already tried to rasterize the smart object layers or flatten the image? How do you in details do the thing that you call "put on the screen"? Maybe set blending mode of a layer? Can you insert a clear screenshot of the full layers panel when the problematic layer is selected?

Comment: I tried blending options it look good but after saving the image it's like it save without the blending I made, I tried to rasterize as well but nothing works.

Comment: An image with layers and blending modes can be saved as a PNG, but a blending mode won't work on a single layer. It needs layers below to blend with.  PNGs don't support layers or blending modes.

Answer (score 1):

This is anything but sure because you haven't revealed what "put on screen " means.

I guess you have a partially transparent layer which has complex black and white gradient patterns. On a background layer they look not so pleasant:

[image]

But if you set the blending mode =Screen, the effect is what's wanted:

[image]

Now you search a way to store the decorative shape layer as partially transparent PNG so that it would give the wanted effect when it's layered on a background WITHOUT other blending than normal. That's a little peculiar because blending mode Screen should be supported in web browsers and all pro level image and video editing programs. But you will get it.

1) rasterize the Black and white shape layer, select all and copy the layer content to clipboard. Shut the shape layer.

2) create a new layer, fill it with white and give to it a layer mask

3) fill the layer mask with black; you can reach the layer mask by clicking its icon in the layers panel

4) take the layer mask to onscreen editing by clicking its icon and holding Alt key at the same time

5) paste in place the shape from the clipboard. Click again the image icon in the layers panel and then the layer mask icon to get the mask for off-screen editing. Apply curves to the mask for wanted effect depth:

[image]

Without curves the black seems to fade a little too fast.

Now you can shut the background layer and save as PNG. The result is usable as overlay with normal blend mode.